# How to add some cutom code to post method in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django rest framework. I was trying to build a API where I want to edit the POST method so that I could execute some actions and change some data from the POST body.
I tried to follow some documentations and Guide from django rest framework website but didnt followed any. Please help me.

Here I need to set some values for some fields that are going to be saved in the database.
views.py

```
from .models import LoginActivity
from .serializers import LoginActivitySerializers

class LoginActivity(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LoginActivity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoginActivitySerializers
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'LoginActivity', views.LoginActivity, basename='LoginActivity')

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
appname='api'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import LoginActivity

class LoginActivitySerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LoginActivity
        fields = ('id', 'user_id', 'datetimelog', 'device_os', 'device_token', 'device_model')
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override rest framework `create` method which come from `viewsets.ModelViewSet` and update request data or perform some other actions.

```
from .models import LoginActivity
from .serializers import LoginActivitySerializers

class LoginActivity(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LoginActivity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoginActivitySerializers

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here you have your post data in request.data
        data = request.data
        # you can do some action here just before create action
        # after that you can call super method or return your response
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```